# Convert dictionary to a list where values are summed for any repeated key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am new to python and working on an assignment where I need to convert a dictionary to a list where values are summed for repeated keys.

I used a dictionary comprehension to convert the dictionary to a compressed one but struggling to add a conditional statement to return summed values for repeated keys. Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
d1 = {'inds': [0, 3, 7, 3, 3, 5, 1], 'vals': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]}

d2 = {k:v for k,v in zip(d1["inds"],d1["vals"])}
print(d2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Summed values`? Please provide an example of your final output for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
from itertools import compress  
d2 = dict((k, sum(compress(d1['vals'], (x == k for x in d1['inds'])))) for k in set(d1['inds']))
```

However, it is not that much intuitive. I hope someone comes up with a better answer :)